How to create a dynamic Y-axis scale in Highcharts without floating point values?
I'm working on implementing Highcharts for visualizing data in my web application. I need to create a dynamic Y-axis scale that avoids displaying floating point values such as 0.1, 1.5, or 3.5, and instead only shows whole numbers.
Note: Currently Highchart is dynamically scaling Y- Axis based on Number of Bar(Columns) & its max value but for lower value for E.g. with 1 bar having max value as 1 its showing in fraction as seen below:
enter image description here
I want the tickInterval for the Y-axis scale to be automatically derived based on the maximum value of the chart. The solution should also apply to drilldown charts, ensuring consistent behavior across all chart levels.
Can anyone provide guidance on how to achieve this in Highcharts? Any help or insights would be greatly appreciated.
I've tried a few approaches to address this issue, including rounding up values and manually setting the tickInterval for the Y-axis. However, these solutions result in a messy appearance, especially when the count of data points goes into the hundreds or thousands. Additionally, setting a minimum value of 1 instead of 0 didn't fully address the problem.
My expectation is to have a Y-axis scale that dynamically adjusts to the maximum value of the chart data, ensuring that only whole numbers are displayed and that the tickInterval is appropriately derived based on the data range. This solution should also apply seamlessly to drilldown charts, maintaining consistency across all chart levels.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
